# Token or value put in a var with extra brackets

Tags: karate

Using karate standalone jar version 0.9.5

I am getting a header value, which is a token for later use.

I have an authentication feature. I'm getting the value this way:

```
* def token = responseHeaders['token']
```

When I print the token I get a string (Example):

> "123456"

However when I try to concatenate that token with any other string (Example):

```
 Then print "Bearer " + token
```

I get this. Two extra brackets around the token string are added:

> "Bearer [123456]"

Same thing happens when I try to user Karate.callSingle() to get my token as global variable in the js config file:

```
 var result = karate.callSingle('authentication.feature', config);
 config.token = result.token;
```

Seems like the issue happens when I try to concatenate a string with a variable.

Is there any workaround? I tried to use js functions such as slice or substring inside karate-config.js but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
* def token = responseHeaders['token'][0]
```

This is mentioned in the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#responseheaders

Comment: Thanks, goofy of me to miss that